# "Undefined offset: 1" or not correct routing in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

To be frank, this problem is already tired, so I haven't tried to do, I'm not coming out to fix it. On the local server, everything works fine.

var/www/ - project

/var/www/yii - yii framework

The code is correct because everything works on the local server.

**SiteController.php**

```
public function actionStart() 
    {
        $featured = Page::model()->findAllByAttributes(
            array(),
            $condition  = 'featured = :featureId',
            $params     = array(
                ':featureId' => 1,
            )
        );
        $this->layout='/layouts/start/main';
        $this->render('/layouts/start/start', array('featured'=>$featured));
    }
```

protected / views / layouts / start / main.php
http://pastebin.com/4RzF0Y9d

protected / views / layouts / start / start.php

```
<!--page_container-->
    <div class="page_container">
        <!--slider-->
        <div id="main_slider">
            <div class="camera_wrap" id="camera_wrap_1">
                <div data-src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/start/slider/1.jpg"></div>
                <div data-src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/start/slider/2.jpg"></div>
                <div data-src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/start/slider/3.jpg"></div>                                        
            </div><!-- #camera_wrap_1 -->
            <div class="clear"></div>  
        </div>        
        <!--//slider-->

        <!--planning-->
        <div class="wrap planning">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span3">
                        <a href="#">
                                <span class="img_icon icon1"></span>
                            <span class="link_title">egestas dolor</span>
                                Nunc vel arcu arcu. Nulla mollis feugiat dui id tincidunt. Aenean ac lobortis elit.
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <a href="#">
                                <span class="img_icon icon2"></span>
                            <span class="link_title">lorem ipsum</span>
                                Nunc vel arcu arcu. Nulla mollis feugiat dui id tincidunt. Aenean ac lobortis elit.
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <a href="#">
                                <span class="img_icon icon3"></span>
                            <span class="link_title">vestilum eget</span>
                                Nunc vel arcu arcu. Nulla mollis feugiat dui id tincidunt. Aenean ac lobortis elit.
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <a href="#">
                                <span class="img_icon icon4"></span>
                            <span class="link_title">nulla feugiat</span>
                                Nunc vel arcu arcu. Nulla mollis feugiat dui id tincidunt. Aenean ac lobortis elit.
                        </a>
                    </div>                              
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--//planning-->

        <!--Welcome-->
        <div class="wrap block">
            <div class="container welcome_block">
                <div class="welcome_line welcome_t"></div>
                Cras vulputate pretium massa gravida egestas consectetur?<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet &amp; consectetur adipiscing elit!</span>
                <div class="welcome_line welcome_b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--//Welcome-->
        <div id="content">
    <!--featured works-->
    <div class="wrap block carousel_block">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="upper">featured advertisements</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
                        <li>
                            <div class="hover_img">
                                <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/page/<?=$featured[0]['id']?>"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?><?=$featured[0]['picture_1']?>" alt="<?=$featured[0]['title']?>" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="hover_img">
                                <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/page/<?=$featured[1]['id']?>"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?><?=$featured[1]['picture_1']?>" alt="<?=$featured[1]['title']?>" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="hover_img">
                                <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/page/<?=$featured[2]['id']?>"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?><?=$featured[2]['picture_1']?>" alt="<?=$featured[2]['title']?>" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="hover_img">
                                <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/page/<?=$featured[3]['id']?>"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?><?=$featured[3]['picture_1']?>" alt="<?=$featured[3]['title']?>" /></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--//featured works-->

    <!--Latest news-->
    <div class="wrap block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row news_block">
                <div class="span6">
                    <h2 class="title">egestas sed convallis metus!</h2>
                    <p>Vestibulum tincidunt ultricies aliquam. Donec porta mi nec tortor sagittis rhoncus. Nunc ante arcu, ornaresit gravida rutrum ut, facilisis et lacus. Aliquam mauris arcu, interdum eu fermentum tincidunt.</p>
                    <ul class="the-icons grey">
                        <li><i class="icon-time"></i> Curabitur eu placerat massa.</li>
                        <li><i class="icon-star"></i> Integer adipiscing velit nec purus facilisis ut pharetra!</li>
                        <li><i class="icon-camera"></i> Nunc mollis, nisl vel tincidunt vestibulum, lacus libero mollis urna, eu dapibus lacus nisi et nulla.</li>
                        <li><i class="icon-qrcode"></i> Curabitur veltpat magna. Pellentesque pellentesque dapibus dictum. </li>
                        <li><i class="icon-user"></i> Nulla ut erat ut massa molestie commodo.</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Duis vel ligula et libero iaculis facilisis in vel justo. Duis lacinia orci ut tellus interdum dignissim. Fusce eugei scelerisque enim. Phasellus nec libero lectus. Quisque posuere mi non nibh facilisis semper. Donec lorem suscipit est sed mauris eleifend congue. Class taciti sociosqu litora torquent <a href="#" class="arrow_link">per conubia.</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                    <h2 class="title">Latest news</h2>
                    <ul id="newscarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
                        <li>
                            <div class="news_date">15 apr<span>2019</span></div>
                            <div class="news_t"><a href="#">Sed massa dui, porta corper ac varius!</a></div>
                            <div class="news">Posted by <a href="#">Anna Smith</a>  /  In <a href="#">City</a><br/>Tags: <a href="#">eget</a>, <a href="#">mauris</a></div>
                            <div class="news_info">Tristique tincidunt cursus sed, ornare ncidunt eque a tristique. Phasellus porttitor mollis tortor etoq vestibulum. Quisque non lacus tortor, quis cumsan nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur icing elit. Nullam pulvinarteses lorem sed dui euismod eget. <a href="#">Read more...</a></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="news_date">05 apr<span>2019</span></div>
                            <div class="news_t"><a href="#">eget &amp; massa viviamu marius mas</a></div>
                            <div class="news">Posted by <a href="#">Anna Smith</a>  /  In <a href="#">City</a><br/>Tags: <a href="#">eget</a>, <a href="#">mauris</a></div>
                            <div class="news_info">Cursus sed, aliquet nec odio. Integer ornare tincidunt neque a tristique. Phasellus porttitor millis tortor etoq vestibulum. Quisque ont lacus toirtor uis accumsan nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ulvinarteses em sed. <a href="#">Read more...</a></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="news_date">15 apr<span>2019</span></div>
                            <div class="news_t"><a href="#">Sed massa dui, porta corper ac varius!</a></div>
                            <div class="news">Posted by <a href="#">Anna Smith</a>  /  In <a href="#">City</a><br/>Tags: <a href="#">eget</a>, <a href="#">mauris</a></div>
                            <div class="news_info">Tristique tincidunt cursus sed, ornare ncidunt eque a tristique. Phasellus porttitor mollis tortor etoq vestibulum. Quisque non lacus tortor, quis cumsan nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur icing elit. Nullam pulvinarteses lorem sed dui euismod eget. <a href="#">Read more...</a></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="news_date">05 apr<span>2019</span></div>
                            <div class="news_t"><a href="#">eget &amp; massa viviamu marius mas</a></div>
                            <div class="news">Posted by <a href="#">Anna Smith</a>  /  In <a href="#">City</a><br/>Tags: <a href="#">eget</a>, <a href="#">mauris</a></div>
                            <div class="news_info">Cursus sed, aliquet nec odio. Integer ornare tincidunt neque a tristique. Phasellus porttitor millis tortor etoq vestibulum. Quisque ont lacus toirtor uis accumsan nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ulvinarteses em sed. <a href="#">Read more...</a></div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Latest news-->

    <!--latest posts-->
    <div class="wrap block carousel_block">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="upper">latest advertisements</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <ul id="mycarousel2" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
                        <li>
                            <div class="post_carousel">
                                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/start/home_blog/1.jpg" alt="" />
                                <div class="title_t"><a href="#">ipsum dolor ac egestas mas</a></div>
                                <div class="post_meta">
                                    Posted by <a href="#">John Doe</a>  /  15 apr  / In <a href="#">Vacation</a>
                                </div>
                                Ut nisl turpis, tristique tincidunt cursus sed, aliquet nec odio. Integer ornare tincidunt neque a ristiquet phasellus mollis tortor. <a href="#" class="arrow_link">Read more...</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="post_carousel">
                                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/start/home_blog/2.jpg" alt="" />
                                <div class="title_t"><a href="#">vestibulum egestas tortor</a></div>
                                <div class="post_meta">
                                    Posted by <a href="#">John Doe</a>  /  15 apr  / In <a href="#">Vacation</a>
                                </div>
                                Ut nisl turpis, tristique tincidunt cursus sed, aliquet nec odio. Integer ornare tincidunt neque a ristiquet phasellus mollis tortor. <a href="#" class="arrow_link">Read more...</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="post_carousel">
                                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/start/home_blog/3.jpg" alt="" />
                                <div class="title_t"><a href="#">Quisque sodales dolor</a></div>
                                <div class="post_meta">
                                    Posted by <a href="#">John Doe</a>  /  15 apr  / In <a href="#">Vacation</a>
                                </div>
                                Ut nisl turpis, tristique tincidunt cursus sed, aliquet nec odio. Integer ornare tincidunt neque a ristiquet phasellus mollis tortor. <a href="#" class="arrow_link">Read more...</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="post_carousel">
                                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/start/home_blog/4.jpg" alt="" />
                                <div class="title_t"><a href="#">ipsum dolor ac egestas mas</a></div>
                                <div class="post_meta">
                                    Posted by <a href="#">John Doe</a>  /  15 apr  / In <a href="#">Vacation</a>
                                </div>
                                Ut nisl turpis, tristique tincidunt cursus sed, aliquet nec odio. Integer ornare tincidunt neque a ristiquet phasellus mollis tortor. <a href="#" class="arrow_link">Read more...</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="post_carousel">
                                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/start/home_blog/1.jpg" alt="" />
                                <div class="title_t"><a href="#">Tristique cursus tincidunt</a></div>
                                <div class="post_meta">
                                    Posted by <a href="#">John Doe</a>  /  15 apr  / In <a href="#">Vacation</a>
                                </div>
                                Ut nisl turpis, tristique tincidunt cursus sed, aliquet nec odio. Integer ornare tincidunt neque a ristiquet phasellus mollis tortor. <a href="#" class="arrow_link">Read more...</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="post_carousel">
                                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/img/start/home_blog/2.jpg" alt="" />
                                <div class="title_t"><a href="#">ipsum dolor ac egestas mas</a></div>
                                <div class="post_meta">
                                    Posted by <a href="#">John Doe</a>  /  15 apr  / In <a href="#">Vacation</a>
                                </div>
                                Ut nisl turpis, tristique tincidunt cursus sed, aliquet nec odio. Integer ornare tincidunt neque a ristiquet phasellus mollis tortor. <a href="#" class="arrow_link">Read more...</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--//latest posts-->
</div>
    <!--//page_container-->

    <!--footer-->
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h2 class="title">Latest tweets</h2>
                        <div class="tweet_block"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h2 class="title">Get in touch!</h2>
                        <form action="#" method="post">
                            <input class="span3" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Name" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Name') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Name';" />
                            <input class="span3" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Email" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Email') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Email';" />
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="span3" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Message') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Message';" >Message</textarea>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <input type="reset" class="btn dark_btn" value="Clear form" />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn send_btn" value="Send!" />
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h2 class="title">Testimonials</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <span class="testimonials_arrow"></span>Orci nisi, luctus vitae imperdiet a, iquam vel urna. Pellentesque tincidunt laoreet est, in tristique sapien consequat a purus at ullamcorper pulvinar, massa libero magna.
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div class="author">Anna Smith, Company inc.</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="testimonials_arrow"></span>Luctus vitae imperdiet a, iquamorci nisi lorem. Pellentesque tincidunt laoreet est, in tristique sapien consequat a purus at ullam pulvinar, massa libero consequat egestas mas.
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div class="author">John Doe, Company inc.</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <h2 class="title">our partners</h2>
                        <div class="flickrs">
                            <div class="FlickrImages">
                                <ul></ul>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- content -->
```

Please help because I can not solve this problem for a few days, if you provide any information to give. Thank you!

Comment: Would you copy your layouts to the question? If those links break, people will not be able to read the question in future.

Comment: Which line has the error? It should say in the error message. Also, if you have a routing file, please edit that into your question.

Comment: can you post `var_dump($featured)` or `print_r($featured)`

Comment: the maximum number of characters, halfer 30000, and I have therefore not one file 30720 fit. If you go to this address, all errors will be visible.

Comment: I can't do this, because nothing is displayed. I think it's 'NULL'. But should return array like $featured[1]['id'], $featured[2]['id']... etc like in local server. May be me to publish the rules in main.php file urlmanager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop in your carousel instead of repeating yourself. You probably have a Page::model()->findAllByAttributes() probably returns 1 model on your page which is why  fails.

Just loop through the $featured array instead:

```
<?php foreach ($featured as $item) : ?>
<li>
    <div class="hover_img">
        <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/page/<?=$item->id; ?>"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . $item->picture_1; ?>" alt="<?=$item->title; ?>" /></a>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

A couple more things wrong with this:

- Create your url with createUrl instead
- Always CHtml::encode things like your alt tag

Didn't look further. Too much code :)

Comment: Thanks for the truth! Such comments are valuable!